# Merging two strings that are the same, that appear in a row within an array using JS

Tags: javascript

For example:

`const items = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'];`

Would become:

`['a', 'b', 'a']`

Is there a clean way of doing the above using JS?

I have tried:

```js
const items = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'];
const uniqueInRow = [];

for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
  item = items[i];

  if (item !== item[i++]) {
    uniqueInRow.push(item);
  }
}

console.log(uniqueInRow);
```

Comment: I know how to solve uniques within an array, but not like above, where if its unique in a row

Comment: @LaytonGB getting the unique values would produce `["a", "b"]` not `["a", "b", "a"]`

Comment: You'll want to look closer at `item !== item[i++]`

Answer (score 3):

Try like following:

```js
const items = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'];
const res = []
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0 || items[i] !== items[i-1]) res.push(items[i])
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid equal neighbours via oneliner:

```
vals.forEach((v, i) => (i < vals.length && v === vals[i + 1]) && vals.splice(i, 1))
```